# Email Timeout C#

Tags: c#

I have a program that sends an email with attachments, it works fine at home with a good internet connection but times out when I use a slower connection.

Does anyone know if I can extend the time out so it will send over a slower network.

The code I use is

```
Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;

MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");

mail.From = new MailAddress(FilePaths.Default.SquadronEmailAddress);
mail.To.Add(FilePaths.Default.Email);
mail.Subject = FilePaths.Default.SquadronNumber + " Gliding Training Return";
mail.Body = "Please find attached todays Training Return from " + FilePaths.Default.SquadronNumber +
    ". Please do not reply to this email address as its unmonitored. " +
    "If you have any questions or require further information please contact the Adj on adj.644vgs@aircadets.org";
mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(FilePaths.Default.GlidingTrainingReturnFolder + ("\\Gliding Training Return" + date.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy") + ".pdf")));

SmtpServer.Port = 587;
SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(FilePaths.Default.SquadronEmailAddress, FilePaths.Default.DatabasePassword);
SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

SmtpServer.Send(mail);
MessageBox.Show("Email Sent");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `timeout` property of the `SmtpClient` class

```
SmtpServer.timeout = 200000 ; //change it as needed
```

specifies the time-out value in milliseconds. The default value is 100,000 (100 seconds).

By the way calling `SmtpServer` a variable that is actually a `SmtpClient` is very bad practice

For more details see 
[this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.timeout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can change the timeout by modifying the [`SmtpClient.Timeout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.timeout.aspx) property. It defaults to 100 seconds, which is already a lot, so if you are really exceeding that, you might want to look for a different solution instead. You could for example upload the attachment somewhere and send a link instead—the recipient will thank you too.